# Parsing dhcpd.leases with Python and Regex

Tags: python, regex

We're working on cleaning up some DHCP issues and I'm using Python and regex to parse the dhcpd.leases file. I want to write a single regex that captures each lease (see file sample at the bottom) block and then captures the IP address and MAC. My regex knowledge is rudimentary, but I think I'm on the right track. What I have so far isn't capturing everything:

Code so far:

```
import sys, re

fp = '/Users/smitty/Dropbox/Company/Network/DHCP-Info/dhcpd.leases'
f = open(fp)
ftext = f.read()

p = re.compile(ur'(lease\s([\d]*.*).*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*ethernet\s(.*);*.\n.*\n.*})')

raw_record = []

parsed_record = {}

for match in re.findall(p, ftext):
    raw_record.append(match)

for record in raw_record:
    m = re.search(p, record)
    parsed_record[m.group(2)] = m.group(3)

plaintext_record = []

for ip, mac in parsed_record.iteritems():
    plaintext_record.append("IP: {0}   MAC: {1}".format(ip, mac))
```

Sample block of the dhcpd.leases file:

```
lease 192.168.124.118 {
  starts 1 2014/12/01 12:42:49;
  ends 1 2014/12/01 20:42:49;
  tstp 1 2014/12/01 20:42:49;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:d5:ff:cb;
  uid "\001\000\014)\325\377\313";
}
lease 192.168.124.117 {
  starts 5 2015/05/01 18:49:10;
  ends 6 2015/05/02 02:49:10;
  tstp 6 2015/05/02 02:49:10;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:85:6f:62;
  uid "\001\000\014)\205ob";
}
lease 192.168.124.116 {
  starts 5 2015/06/05 14:48:40;
  ends 5 2015/06/05 22:48:40;
  tstp 5 2015/06/05 22:48:40;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:d1:3e:0d;
  uid "\001\000\014)\321>\015";
}
lease 192.168.123.200 {
  starts 5 2012/07/13 11:54:46;
  ends 5 2012/07/13 11:57:42;
  tstp 5 2012/07/13 11:57:42;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 88:c6:63:c6:08:52;
  uid "\001\210\306c\306\010R";
}
```

I also can't help but feel like I'm all over the place in regards to convention here (creating a list then a dict and then a list again).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn the "multiline" mode on to simplify the expression and avoid checking every newline inside a lease and capture IP and MAC addresses into saving groups:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"lease ([0-9.]+) {.*?hardware ethernet ([:a-f0-9]+);.*?}", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

with open("/Users/smitty/Dropbox/Company/Network/DHCP-Info/dhcpd.leases") as f:
    for match in pattern.finditer(f.read()):
        print(match.group(1), match.group(2))
```

Prints:

```
192.168.124.118 00:0c:29:d5:ff:cb
192.168.124.117 00:0c:29:85:6f:62
192.168.124.116 00:0c:29:d1:3e:0d
192.168.123.200 88:c6:63:c6:08:52
```

Comment: For the second group...I think you might want to change it to `[:a-f0-9]` as MAC addresses are Hexadecimal by nature. And also, I think it's a better idea to give matching groups names like `(?P<IP>[0-9.]+)`...just a matter of opinion

Comment: I like this -- trying it now and........ fantastic. Was previously unfamiliar with `re.MULTILINE` and `re.DOTALL`

I'm going to use this script in conjunction with some command line bash called in linux to streamline an untangling (a logical untangling) of our network. Muchas gracias, danke, grazie, merci, and all that.

@IronFist -- I'd plus 1 you if I were able

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly different solution:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r"(?<=lease )(\S+).*?(\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}).*?(?=\})",
                re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

plaintext_record = []

with open('data.txt', 'r') as fp:
    data = fp.read()

    for m in rx.finditer(data):
        plaintext_record.append('IP: {0}   MAC: {1}'.format(m.group(1), m.group(2)))

for item in plaintext_record:
    print(item)
```

Based on your sample data stored in file `data.txt`, this application will store IP, MAC pair in `plaintext_record` array as you are doing  code.

Printing `plaintext_record`:

```
IP: 192.168.124.118   MAC: 00:0c:29:d5:ff:cb
IP: 192.168.124.117   MAC: 00:0c:29:85:6f:62
IP: 192.168.124.116   MAC: 00:0c:29:d1:3e:0d
IP: 192.168.123.200   MAC: 88:c6:63:c6:08:52
```

Comment: Since you already built your regex pattern, why do you call `re.finditer` instead of `rx.finditer`? ...it will be faster with the already compiled pattern.

Comment: @IronFist good catch I'll update code. Thanks for bringing it up.